# Minage usage in powershell

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to delete files which are too long filenames in Windows 10 but this powershell scripts delete all files even some files's modified date is newer than minage date. Could you please help me to solve that problem?

```
$directory="C:\Users\test\Downloads\aaa" 
mkdir empty_dir
robocopy empty_dir $directory /MINAGE:20210101 /mir
rmdir empty_dir
rmdir $directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `/minage` `/maxage` options on apply to the *SOURCE* folder, and does not check against the destination folder.

In that case, the `/MINAGE` options would run the check for the *empty_dir* folder and it's content, find nothing (as it's an empty folder) and then move on to the purge operations.

I don't think that robocopy is the right tool if your goal is only to delete files.

Maybe you should try using PowerShell `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item` commands:

```
 Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\test\Downloads\aaa" -recurse -include *.* | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt '01/01/2021'} | Remove-Item
```

You can remove the `-recurse` options if you only want to remove files from the top folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it work for delete files which are longer than 260 character?

Comment: By default, it will not support long paths, no.
If you run on an up to date Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016 or later, you can enable long path support . Maybe give it a try ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: I already have long path files in my local pc so i want to delete them but i don't know how to perform it